# Is iCloud Document Sync "delta sync" or "full file sync"?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud

I don't mean iWork docs but for example personal docs in GoodReader `iCloud` folder and perhaps Mac OS `~/Library/Mobile Documents`.

Is there any official documentation about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delta. It splits this intelligently into chunks and only updates the relevant chunks using Rabin fingerprinting.

You can see this in Apple's WWDC [iCloud presentation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#icloud-storage-overview), and 
[slides](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/501_icloud_storage.pdf).

A pretty good description of this chunking can be seen in Siracusa's [Lion review](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2011/07/mac-os-x-10-7.ars/14#versioning-internals), however the review describes this process in terms of document versioning, but the fundamentals are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is full file sync.  The delta aspect that you are wondering about would be with Versions (or Time Machine), and that is a separate set of functionality beyond the scope of iCloud's Documents.

Comment: Can you provide a source to back this up?